# Why is the YAML of "kubectl get" so different from the YAML of "kubectl apply" in GKE?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, manifest, kubectl

I have a GKE cluster.

I used `kubectl apply` to apply the following YAML from my local machine:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-app-svc
  namespace: myapp
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    component: flask-app
```

Got applied. All Good. ✅

---

Then I used `kubectl get service` to get back the YAML from the cluster. It returned this:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/neg: '{"ingress":true}'
    cloud.google.com/neg-status: '{"network_endpoint_groups":{"5000":"k8s1-5fe0c3c1-myapp-flask-app-svc-5000-837dba94"},"zones":["asia-southeast1-a"]}'
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"flask-app-svc","namespace":"myapp"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":5000,"targetPort":5000}],"selector":{"component":"flask-app"}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-10-29T14:40:49Z"
  name: flask-app-svc
  namespace: myapp
  resourceVersion: "242820340"
  uid: ad80f634-5aab-4147-8f71-11ccc44fd867
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.22.52.180
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.22.52.180
  ports:
  - port: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5000
  selector:
    component: flask-app
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

---

#### 1. What kubernetes "concept" is at play here?

#### 2. Why are the 2 YAMLs SO DIFFERENT from each other?

#### 3. What is happening under the hood?

#### 4. Is this specific to GKE, or would any k8s cluster behave this way?

#### 5. Where can I find some info/articles to learn more about this concept?

---

Thank you in advance.

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for a while. Appreciate any help you can advise and suggest here.

Comment: Looks like you have something that adds two annotations for "neg" in Google Cloud. Could it be something related to this? https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-autoneg-controller

Comment: @jonas You maybe correct. This particular annotation addition might've been brought in by the AutoNEG. But as you can see, it's not just the annotations that got added. It's a lot more things. I am trying to get a more ground level understanding about how (and why) GKE decides to add some attributes and values and how it does not.

Comment: All the other additions makes sense, and are common for Kubernetes.

Comment: I understand the auto-added lines make sense and are common for kubernetes. I am trying to understand, how does k8s know which lines to auto-add since these lines were not added by me. Is there any api? Is there any glossary which k8s looks up to auto-add any missing line. Is there any known package structure which tells GKE which lines are missing so that it can add those? Etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kubernetes API server validates and configures data for the API objects which include pods, services, replication controllers, and others. The API Server services REST operations and provides the frontend to the cluster's shared state through which all other components interact. The API server takes the definitions provided by the user to create all the detailed definitions needed to create the objects required. In [this document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest) you can find an overview of the GKE API server engine.

You can find an [example on this document about a create operation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#create-deployment-v1-apps). There you can switch between the request input and the response generated for the API server to create the complete definition of the objects required, its parameters, metadata and all the related configuration parameters that you see in the "extended" version of the original yaml file.
In the same document you can find additional information about this topic.

Answer (score 1):

A [service in GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service) is a way to expose to the intended final users, those applications running in a set of pods. All these elements form part of a GKE cluster.
If you apply a YAML to crate a service, several additional thins are needed in order to have the applications reachable for your users. One of the features of kubernetes and of GKE is to automatically create, set and mantain the resources required to, in this case for example, create a service. All those extra settings and definitions made by GKE are recorded in a YAML file.

If you can know more about this concept, you can start in the [Google Kubernetes Engine product page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine), or consult in this same page the [GKE documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs). Another good point to start is to read this [GKE overview](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/kubernetes-engine-overview).

Comment: Dear @JesusHuesca. Thanks for replying. The doc links you shared are general marketing introduction of GKE cluster - kubernetes in google. They don't cover technicals of why and how so much contents in the YAML get AUTOMATICALLY ADDED by the GKE itself.